# Windows graphics orders implementation in java

Tags: java, windows, rdp, brush

Anybody knows how implemented [PatBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc241602%28PROT.10%29.aspx) in JAVA. Or have some additional info about Brush.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that I know of is `TexturePaint`.